# Summarise null rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a dataset like this:

```
+---------------+-------+
| SAMPLE_NUMBER | SCORE |
+---------------+-------+
|             1 | 100   |
|             2 | 97    |
|             3 | 124   |
|             4 | 762   |
|             5 | 999   |
|             6 | 1200  |
|             7 | NULL  |
|             8 | NULL  |
|             9 | NULL  |
|            10 | NULL  |
+---------------+-------+
```

I want to be able to summarise the NULL rows instead of displaying them all. So ideally, I would want the above to look like this:

```
+---------------+-------+
| SAMPLE_NUMBER | SCORE |
+---------------+-------+
| 1             | 100   |
| 2             | 97    |
| 3             | 124   |
| 4             | 762   |
| 5             | 999   |
| 6             | 1200  |
| 7-10          | NULL  |
+---------------+-------+
```

Is there any way in Oracle to do this? Or is it something I will have to do post-query?

Comment: just a guess: use coalesce

Comment: Using of `UNION` can be useful, part one has no null and second part has a record in your formatted, and don't forget about data-type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that this should be part of your presentation layer since you will have to cast sample_number to a string (assuming it is a numeric type. An alternative to your requirements is to return the min and max consecutive sample_number:

```
with t (SAMPLE_NUMBER, SCORE) as (
    values  (1, 100)
        ,   (2, 97)
        ,   (3, 124)
        ,   (4, 762)
        ,   (5, 999)
        ,   (6, 1200)
        ,   (7, NULL)
        ,   (8, NULL)
        ,   (9, NULL)
        ,   (10, NULL)
)
select min(sample_number), max(sample_number), grp, score
from (
    select SAMPLE_NUMBER, SCORE
       ,   row_number() over (order by SAMPLE_NUMBER)
       -   row_number() over (partition by SCORE
                              order by SAMPLE_NUMBER) as grp
    from t
) group by grp, score
order by grp;

1           2           GRP                  SCORE      
----------- ----------- -------------------- -----------
      1           1                    0         100
      2           2                    1          97
      3           3                    2         124
      4           4                    3         762
      5           5                    4         999
      6           6                    5        1200
      7          10                    6           -
```

Tried against db2, so you may have to adjust it slightly.

Edit: treat rows as individuals when score is not null

```
with t (SAMPLE_NUMBER, SCORE) as (
    values  (1, 100)
        ,   (2, 97)
        ,   (3, 97)
        ,   (4, 762)
        ,   (5, 999)
        ,   (6, 1200)
        ,   (7, NULL)
        ,   (8, NULL)
        ,   (9, NULL)
        ,   (10, NULL)
)
select min(sample_number), max(sample_number), grp, score
from (
    select SAMPLE_NUMBER, SCORE
       ,   row_number() over (order by SAMPLE_NUMBER)
       -   row_number() over (partition by SCORE
                              order by SAMPLE_NUMBER) as grp
    from t
) group by grp, score
         , case when score is not null then sample_number end
order by grp;

1           2           GRP                  SCORE      
----------- ----------- -------------------- -----------
      1           1                    0         100
      2           2                    1          97
      3           3                    1          97
      4           4                    3         762
      5           5                    4         999
      6           6                    5        1200
      7          10                    6           -
```

You may want to map max to null in case it is the same as min:

```
[...]
select min(sample_number)
     , nullif(max(sample_number), min(sample_number))
     , grp
     , score
from ...

1           2           GRP                  SCORE      
----------- ----------- -------------------- -----------
      1           -                    0         100
      2           -                    1          97
      3           -                    1          97
      4           -                    3         762
      5           -                    4         999
      6           -                    5        1200
      7          10                    6           -
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - this works in most situations but not if there are duplicate scores. How can we make this work if there are duplicate scores?

Comment: Assume `update t set score = 97 where sample_number = 3`. What should the result look like? The current query returns min=2, max=3, score=97, what is your expected output?

Comment: I would want it to return min=3, max=3, score=97

Comment: Do you also want 1 row for 2,2,97 or do you want to skip that one?

Comment: Yes, a row should be returned for all results if the result is not null

Comment: You can use a similar trick as Gordon did, use the sample_number in the group by clause when score has a value. I'll update the answer with that.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  For your sample data:

```
select (case when score is null then min(sample_number) || '-' || max(sample_number)
             else min(sample_number)
        end) as sample_number,
       score
from table t
group by score
order by min(id)
```

In other words, `group by score` and then fiddle with the sample number.  Note:  this assumes that you do not have duplicate scores.  If you do, you can do so with a more complicated version:

```
select (case when score is null then min(sample_number) || '-' || max(sample_number)
             else min(sample_number)
        end) as sample_number,
       score
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by score order by sample_number) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
group by score, (case when score is not null then seqnum end);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DECODE(SCORE
          ,NULL
          ,(SELECT COUNT()+1 
            FROM TAB_NAME 
            WHERE SCORE IS NOT NULL)
    || '-'
    || (SELECT COUNT() 
        FROM TAB_NAME)
          ,SAMPLE_NUMBER) NUM
   , NVL(TO_CHAR(SCORE),'NULL') SCRE
FROM TAB_NAME
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```